# Can I combine Stoutem created with React Native with a Nativescript app

Tags: mobile, react-native, integration, nativescript

I have a NativeScript application which I would like to integrate, combine, or use with a new integrating app that I would like to build with Stoutem which is developed with Native Script and using it's own Cloud Storage. I would like to leverage the components, extensions or modules already built in Stoutem to use with my existing app.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or have tried it?

I am thinking of the routing or navigation. The data could be shared through API.

Update:
I got a suggestion on loading Stoutem Extensions in a frame under our NativeScript app.

Comment: I do not think that you could combine `Stoutem` with `NativeScript` app. You could use Telerik Platform to build your app, which also provides Cloud Storage - http://www.telerik.com/platform#overview. In regard to that in https://www.npmjs.com/ you could find a lot of plugins, which extends the functionality of NativeScript You could also review nativescript-telerk-ui plugin and its components -http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayTsonev. I'll look in to your suggestions.